# bgzip all VCF files in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash

So I've been trying to bgzip around 100 VCF files in parallel, but although the jobs are submitted and files get created there's definitely something wrong.

So far I've been trying:

```
$for file in *.vcf 

> do

> bsub /foo/bar/bgzip $file

>> $file.gz
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as my websearches suggest, `bgzip` works the same way as `gzip`, you don't specify an output file:

```
for f in *.vcf; do
   bsub bgzip "$f"
done
```

You should also double-quote variables in case your filenames have spaces in them.

Answer (score 2):

you can use GNU parallel.

```
parallel bgzip {} ::: *.vcf
```